# Typo3 and DirectMail - Substitute

Tags: typo3, newsletter, typoscript

The template for my newsletter that I send with DirectMail in Typo3 is like this:

```
<span>DEAR ###USER_first_name### ###USER_last_name###</span>
```

But theres a link to "Show Newsletter in browser". In this case it would be impossible to show the name, since this info is in tt_address and its filled when the Engine sends the email, but I would like to replace it so that at least the user can read:

```
Dear reader,
```

Is there any way to do this, so that the email keep showing the name, while the web version shows the generic greeting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a second page with the generic content and link to that one in your newsletter. That page may also contain some more content, like social media "like buttons", for instance.

Or you may add a parameter to the link which identifies the user, so the web-version may load the data of that specific user from the database. In the last case, it may open up a potential security risk if your parameter is not secure enough and can be guessed or iterated over. So be sure to secure that thing if you make it personalized.